# You can only perform equals comparisons on NaN

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm working with angular 6 and firestore. I have a query:

```
    let cadena=Number(this._tempFirebaseRepo.getCadenaFecha(1));

    //aca esta la query de Firestore
    this.dispositivoRef = this.afs.collection('Dispositivo', ref =>
         ref.where('fecha', '>', cadena)
    )
    debugger;
    this.ultimoDia = this.dispositivoRef.valueChanges();
```

On the browser console appear this error:

> You can only perform equals comparisons on NaN

Comment: have you try `isNaN()` this?

Comment: isNaN()?, where?

Comment: which value you want to check is not a number?

Comment: yes, it is a number

Comment: can you create `https://stackblitz.com/`? and share link with me.

Comment: If you log `this._tempFirebaseRepo.getCadenaFecha(1)`, what does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Number()` method can return NaN in certain cases. For example, `Number('foo')` is not a number, and returns NaN.

You cannot check if a number is 'bigger' or 'smaller' than something that isn't a number, the question itself doesn't make sense.

In this case, check the value of `cadena`. That's where your issue lies.